# Why does catching a const int& by an int& work?

Tags: c++, exception, constants

In the following code, I throw an int, catch it as const int&, re-throw it and catch it again catch it as an int&.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            int x = 1;
            throw x;
        }
        catch(const int& e)
        {
            std::cout << "Inner catch" << std::endl;
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch(int & e1)
    {
        std::cout << "Outer catch" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above program compiles successfully and prints

```
Inner catch
Outer catch
```

On the other hand the following program in which I am trying to initialize an int& by a const int& wouldn't even compile.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    const int& y = x;
    int& z = y 
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error as expected

```
binding ‘const int’ to reference of type ‘int&’ discards qualifiers
     int& z = y
```

Why am I allowed to catch an const int& as an int& but not able to assign cons int& to int&?

Comment: Because exceptions are weird. Strictly speaking, you throw by value but somehow is able to bind a reference to it.

Comment: Why would you be catching an `int` by reference in the first place ?  Just catch the `int`.

Comment: @SidS Thats beside the point.

Comment: `throw e;` is not the correct way to rethrow an exception. You must call `throw;` by itself to rethrow the current exception. Or else throw a new exception.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Changed that.

Answer (score 13):

[except.handle/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/except#handle-3):

> A handler is a match for an exception object of type *E* if
>   (3.1) – The handler is of type *cv T* or *cv T&* and *E* and *T* are the same type (**ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers**), or [...]

Comment: This answer misses the point that `throw` *throws by value*. You cannot, in fact, under any circumstances, throw a reference (at best you could throw a `std::reference_wrapper` etc., but I'll consider that cheating). Good standard reference, but alas, only semi-applicable here.

Comment: @ArneVogel Yes, I can throw a reference: `int i{ 42 }; int &foo{ i }; throw foo;` ^^

Comment: IDK if you are kidding, but this proves my point. First of all, the exception is a new object of type `int` and it is created during the evaluation of the `throw` expression. If you mean to say that the argument to `throw` is an expression of reference type, that is actually not correct either in standard terminology (instead, it is an [*lvalue expression* of type `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)).

Comment: @ArneVogel *IDK if you are kidding* – I am.

Answer (score 6):

A throw is always by value. You can catch it with a `const` or with a reference if you want, but the object thrown is always a copy. So it's perfectly safe to catch it with a non-`const` and to modify it. You can test this by printing the address of an `int`, then throw it, catch it by reference, and print the address of the reference. You'll see it's a different address.

You can even do this:

```
try
{
    throw 3;
}
catch (int& q)
{
    q = 4;
}
```

The value of the thrown object with the value `3` is modified because `q` binds to a new `int` initialized with the thrown value. You always throw a value.

The exception is just `throw;`, which re-throws the existing object. It has to be this way because otherwise, it would be impossible to sanely manage the lifetime of thrown objects.

Comment: All you provide is speculation backed on the behaviour of some implementation. It isn't specified by the standard where the object that is thrown gets stored. Also the standard doesn't require any copying taking place.

Comment: The current (granted, draft) standard does say "Throwing an exception copy-initializes ([dcl.init], [class.copy.ctor]) a temporary object..." and "The memory for the exception object is allocated in an unspecified way,...".  (See [except.throw])  This would seem to say that a copy is required, but doesn't say exactly where that copy is.  (Though I suppose a move would be valid as well)

Comment: @Swordfish Read my last sentence which explains why it has to be this way.